# Why does my cronjob not execute my shell-script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, cron

I have a crontab that creates a dump of my database every night:

```
20 3 * * * /path/to/dailydump.sh
```

`dailydump.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/sh

DATENAME=`date +%Y%m%d`

BASENAME="/path/to/dumps/db_${DATENAME}.sql"

/usr/bin/mysqldump -hhost -uusername -ppassword databasename > ${BASENAME}
```

Permissions are:

```
-rwx---r-x 1 ... dailydump.sh
drwxr-xrwx 2 ... dumps
```

**Why does my cronjob not work?**

I'm on a shared server without root access. There are no logs in `/var/log/cron` or `/var/log/syslog`. There is not mail in `/var/mail/<user_name>` or `/var/spool/mail/<user_name>` (in fact there is nothing at all in `/var/mail/` and `/var/spool/`), `MAILTO=my@email.com` does not mail any error messages, and `1 2 * * *  /path/to/your/command &>/path/to/mycommand.log` does not save any log file. `ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep?` returns nothing. (See https://serverfault.com/a/449652)

The whole setup worked fine until I moved all files to a new domain and had to setup a new crontab. (Yes, I updated all paths and the database login information. I checked it multiple times, too.) I'm with the same hosting provider on the same machine, so the environment has not changed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

#### "Solution"

Okay, this is most strange. The help center of my provider says that if the script to be executed by a cronjob rests inside a password protected directory, I need to add `-auth=user:password -source` before the path to the script. So I added that (with the proper authentication):

> ```
> 20 3 * * * -auth=user:password -source /path/to/dailydump.sh
> ```

The result was that *an error message was emailed to me* (so `MAILTO=` works), telling me `/bin/sh: -=: invalid option` and listing the available options. The example in the help center did not actually give a physical path (`/path/to/file`), but an URL (`http://...`), so I deleted `auth` and `source` again and saved the crontab, and **now the f%§#ing cronjob runs!!** 'The crontab looks exactly like it did before, char for char, but now it runs, with no apparent changes to the code.

I have no idea what the problem was, but inserting wrong code and deleting it again did the trick. o_O It appears as if the cronjob actually *did* run all the time (because when it doesn't, it obviously throws an error), only that it *did nothing!* Very mysterious. If anyone can explain that to me (in a reproducible manner), I'll offer a bounty of 200 and award it (after the necessary wait of two days).

Also, @chaos gave me another solution, completely avoiding the shell script and letting cron dump the database directly (see the comments to his answer below):

> 20 3 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -hhost -uusername -ppassword databasename > /path/to/dumps/db_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d).sql

Just don't forget to escape the percent signs, or the script will find an "unexpected EOF".

Thank you to everyone for your help. I learned a lot again (although not what was wrong here).

Comment: If `ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep` is not returning anything, most probably crond is not running.

Comment: @Sree Crond is running. See my comment to the answer by "chaos" below.

Comment: Strange. I replicated this cron on my test server (Centos 7) on a small database I have and it worked just fine.

Comment: What distro/release? Is SElinux active (and if so file type ok)? Is script ownership ok with crontab owner?

Comment: How do I check distro/release and wether SElinux is active?

Comment: Tell your sysadmin to fix the email problem. In the meantime, add `exec >~/cronjob.log 2>&1; set -x` just below the `#!` line and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure the `cron` daemon is running and honouring the `crontab`, you could make a small test. Edit your `crontab` with an entry like this:

```
* * * * * /bin/date >>/tmp/test
```

After a minute check the file /tmp/test. If there is no file, the daemon is most probably not running. If that's the case I would get in contact with the support of the provider.

**Edit:**

To determine the environment in the cron instance you that:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/id >>/tmp/test
* * * * * /usr/bin/env >>/tmp/test
```

Now see the contents of the file.

Comment: The file is created. So the cron daemon is running.

Comment: @what then there is something with your script. See my edit^^

Comment: Here is the file (with private data edited): `SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
PWD=/path/to/my/webspace [edited]
SHLVL=1
HOME=/kunden/path/to/my/webspace [edited]
LOGNAME=myusername [edited]
_=/usr/bin/env
uid=1060230(myusername[edited]) gid=600(ftpusers) groups=600(ftpusers)`

Comment: @what I assume your user for the ssh access is also `myusername` and has the same uid (check with the `id` command). You can also try the cronjob without a separate script like this: `20 3 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -hhost -uusername -ppassword databasename > /path/to/dumps/db_$(date +%Y%m%d).sql >/tmp/test 2>&1` and see if it works

Comment: @what I wrote it wrong sorry, I meant: `20 3 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -hhost -uusername -ppassword databasename > /path/to/dumps/db_$(date +%Y%m%d).sql 2>/tmp/test`. the errors should be written in /tmp/test now.

Comment: Okay, I needed to escape the percent signs: `+\%Y\%m\%d`. Otherwise the code in your last comment worked fine and a database dump has been created. Maybe I should just skip the .sh-Skript?

Comment: @what if you can I would, it simplifies the task

Comment: I got the cronjob to work. See the edit to my question. I accept your answer, because it is the least I can do for your time and patience, and because you did give me a solution that works. Thank you! I very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Execute the script directly and check if it works.
2. Some of shell environment variables may not be available when the script is running under crontab depending on how you setup the script.

Try modifying the script to test if environment variables is the issue:

```
sh --login -c "/usr/bin/mysqldump -hhost -uusername -ppassword databasename > ${BASENAME} >  /path/to/LogFile.txt 2>&1"
```

Comment: Executing the script directly with `sh dailydump.sh` creates a database dump in the specified folder. So the script is okay.